# I want regex that can take only specific values

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want that user can give only 8-10 pin code like 452001 ,452003 ,452100,452008,45211,452113 otherwise some message.

so please help me to give proper regex.

Comment: Firstly, Stackoverflow is not a community of code monkeys. Show that you have tried to solve it on your own and ask specifically when you have a problem. Secondly, why a regex and not just numerical comparisons (e.g. pin >= 450000)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex

```
<input pattern="^[0-9]{8,10}$">
```

If you wrap the element in a form you can use Angulars form features

```
<form>
  <input pattern="^[0-9]{8,10}$" #pin="ngForm" ngControl="pin">
  <div *ngIf="!pin.valid && pin.touched">
    {{pin.errors | json}}
  <div>
</form>
```